# Sorry, but latex.exe did not suceed

Tags: errors, miktex

I've just installed basic Miktex 2.9.6236-64 bits, on a windows 10 professional 64 operating system. I use WinEdt to edit .tex files and to compile to latex, but when I do it I get this error:
"Sorry, but latex.exe did not suceed"
and a message to look for latex.log which is this:

```
2017-03-13 13:33:48,283+0100 INFO  latex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - Info: 
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - Line: 45
```

I've refreshed fndb and update files and tried again but now log file is:

```
2017-03-13 13:33:48,283+0100 INFO  latex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - Info: 
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2017-03-13 13:33:51,033+0100 FATAL latex - Line: 45
2017-03-13 13:40:56,895+0100 INFO  latex - running 'initexmf --quiet --update-fndb' to refresh the file name database
2017-03-13 13:40:57,114+0100 FATAL latex - The executed process did not succeed.
2017-03-13 13:40:57,114+0100 FATAL latex - Info: fileName="C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe", arguments="--quiet --update-fndb", exitCode="1"
2017-03-13 13:40:57,114+0100 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\Process\Process.cpp
2017-03-13 13:40:57,114+0100 FATAL latex - Line: 159
2017-03-13 13:42:57,235+0100 FATAL latex - GUI framework cannot be initialized.
2017-03-13 13:42:57,235+0100 FATAL latex - Info: 
2017-03-13 13:42:57,235+0100 FATAL latex - Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\UI\Qt\mikuiqt.cpp
2017-03-13 13:42:57,235+0100 FATAL latex - Line: 45
```

but still no work.
What's the problem? On windows 7 prof 64 bits it worked well. Some help please?

More info:
With this basic tex file

```
\documentclass [a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}       
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{eurosym}

\newcount\problemes
\problemes=0
\def\probl{\global\advance\problemes by 1  % \setcounter{punts}{0} \vskip 2ex
\noindent{\bf \the\problemes) }}

\definecolor{verdpxo}{rgb}{.6,1,.4}     % green
\definecolor{grocpastel}{rgb}{1,1,.4}   % yellow

\begin{document}

\vspace{1cm}

\probl Simplify $3\root 4 \of{243}-2\root 4 \of{1875}+5\root 4 \of{768}-4\root 4 \of{3}$

\hfill{\small\sl (algebra)}

\

\probl Product of $x^3-3x^2+3x-1$ i $x^4-4x^3+6x^2-4x+1$

\hfill{\small\sl (polynomial)}

\probl Resolve
$\left\{
\begin{array}{cl}
-x^2-4x+5 & \geq 0  \\
3x+3 & < 0
\end{array}
\right.
$

\hfill{\small\sl (inequalities)}
\end{document}
```

It works well. I can generate a dvi file and print it. But if I add this package

`\usepackage{multirow}` (or `\usepackage{colortbl}` or `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}`)

it fails and get latex.exe did not suceed.

It seems it's unable to compile new packages. Need help.

Comment: Could you provide us with a minimal, failing version the document you are trying to compile? Otherwise we cannot help you find the mistake.

Comment: @Timm the document is unlikely to be relevant to the problem (it is failing to build the format, so you'd get the  same error for every document)

Comment: "GUI framework cannot be initialized" normally means that miktex is trying to start the on-the-fly installation dialog and something is blocking it. At first make sure that everything is really up-to-date (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation/108490#108490) and if the problem persists compile on a command line so get a better error message about the missing package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: WinEdt versions earlier than 10.0 had this problem. Try upgrading to the latest version of WinEdt.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug (I think) in WinEdt versions earlier than 10.0.

This is an excerpt of WinEdt 10.0 Build 20160317 changelog:

> A problem with MiKTeX's "Install Packages on Demand"
>   functionality when running console applications inside WinEdt
>   console has been fixed (regardless of whether the packages are
>   installed on user or system level with UAC and regardless of MiKTeX
>   asking for conformation or not). It turns out that MiKTeX's
>   accessories (except TeXify) cannot initiate download and
>   installation of missing packages with any kind of prompt if the
>   process was created within invisible (hidden) console Window (it is
>   not clear why: a bug in MiKTeX). However, the way around this
>   problem is NOT to create (and then hide) an external console Window
>   at all. Simple enough, once you find out what exactly is the
>   matter...

Simply upgrade to the latest version of WinEdt (now 10.2 Build 20170413) and the problem will be away.